# localhost is currently unable to handle this request. codeigniter problem

Tags: codeigniter

I have this error when i am trying to access a website from wamp, it is done in codeigniter.

**Error:**

`localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500`

**homeindex controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class HomeIndex extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->helper('form','url','file');
        $this->load->library('session','upload');
    }

    public function index()
    {   
        //$this->load->view('coming_soon');
        $this->load->view('homeIndex');
    }
}
```

**route**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'HomeIndex';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

I am able to access other website which are not done using any frameworks.

This website is done using codeigniter. I am not able to access the website.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Could you access a terminal and type `ls -la` at the terminal to see the codeigniter directory permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple loads with one call are done using an array:

```
$this->load->helper(array('form','url','file'));
$this->load->library(array('session','upload'));
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::helper

if that doesn't work turn on error reporting (switch to development mode in `index.php`) and see what the actual error is. 500 error can be many things...

Comment: i have a doubt, whenever i am trying to edit my site on localhost, when i click on the links,its going to live page. how do i stop it

Comment: please keep comments regarding only the question posted above. i've answered your other question.